# Javascript ensure the N seconds passed between log entries

Tags: javascript

I have a logger which writes data every 5 seconds.

It is used for 2 purposes:

1. get the latest data record
2. get the records for 1 month or week.

So, I want it to always keep the latest written record, however ensure that the time frame between records (excluding the last one) is at least one minutes. For that I want to run the db cleanup script periodically.

need help with the algorithm which will remove the db entries which are too close by timestamp.

not working example which removes all records :)

```
let wasRemoved: boolean = true;
while(wasRemoved) {
    const logs = await logsRepository.find({parent: {id: parents[0].id}});
    const startL = logs.length;
    console.log('start: ' + startL);
    for (let i = 0; i < logs.length - 2; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < logs.length-2 &&
              DataHelpers.getSecondsBetweenDates(logs[i].createdAt, logs[i+1].createdAt) < 60) {
            console.log(DataHelpers.getSecondsBetweenDates(logs[i].createdAt, logs[i+1].createdAt));
            logs.splice(i+1, 1);
            wasRemoved = true;
            await logsRepository.delete(logs[i+1].id);
        }
    }
    if (startL === logs.length) wasRemoved = false;
    console.log('end: ' + logs.length);
}
```

basically it always removes the next record. Please help with the proper algorithm to solve this problem.

thanks!

Comment: you can use `setInterval`. This calls a function after `few seconds` mentioned in the second parameter.

Comment: how is that related? data is written every 5 seconds. this problem is to cleanup the data by removing the entries (the point is to ensure that all entries have a time difference > 60 seconds, except the latest one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to filter your logs: just keep the filtered array as an accumulator and at each iteration compare the `createdAt` fields of the current and the last filtered elements:

```js
const logs = [
  {createdAt: 0}, 
  {createdAt: 10}, 
  {createdAt: 30}, 
  {createdAt: 70}, 
  {createdAt: 80}, 
  {createdAt: 90},
  {createdAt: 140},
  {createdAt: 200},
  {createdAt: 210},
  {createdAt: 220}
];

const filtered = logs.reduce((filtered, cur, i, array) => {
  if (!filtered.length || 
      i === array.length - 1 || 
      cur.createdAt - filtered[filtered.length - 1].createdAt >= 60) {
    filtered.push(cur);
  }
  return filtered;
}, []);

console.log(filtered);
```